# How to analyze the file activities due to process?

Tags: linux

I need to analyze the file i/o operations caused due to a process. 
So I would like to know, which all files are affected by this program. Is there a tool for this particular use case?.

One of our debugging for a slow URL processing got the culprit being the file being read each time a URL was processed by the system. So I would like to get recommendations for a tool which would monitor the file activities per process.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` with the `-p` flag, like this : `lsof -p $PID` .

Answer (score 0):

mainly you use ps for evaluating the pid of the process and use the proc filesystem to see the used files by the specific process.
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-get-list-of-open-files/